# Как вставить функцию в динамически созданный элемент js

Tags: javascript, html, функции

Нужно вставить функцию `clic()`, чтобы при нажатии на элемент функция срабатывала, в динамически созданный элемент вот этим кодом:

```
     for (let b = 1; b < tytle.length / c; ++b) {
     let a = document.createElement("a");
     a.innerHTML = b;
     a.src = ('#' + b);
     let stranitca = document.getElementById('stranitca');
     stranitca.appendChild(a);
     }
```

Comment: addEventListener вам в помощь

Comment: a.click = function(){ ... } - не оно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
let tytle = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let c = 1;

for (let b = 1; b < tytle.length / c; ++b) {
     let a = document.createElement("a");
     a.innerHTML = b;
     a.src = ('#' + b);
     a.addEventListener("click", click);
     let stranitca = document.getElementById('stranitca');
     stranitca.appendChild(a);
     stranitca.appendChild(document.createElement("br")); // тупл разделить
}

function click(){
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="stranitca"></div>
```